# Get inputs from user into profile model of Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a registration form which is an extension of `UserCreationForm` and I have a `UserProfileForm`. I am rendering both the forms to the **same html** during user registration.

The problem is, inputs are getting saved to the inbuilt users model but not to the Profile Model. No data is showing up in Profile Model.

I have tried many ways and looked for many solution but unable to find the mistake.

My forms.py looks like this -

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

      email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
      first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
      last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
      username = forms.CharField(required=True)

      class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['username',
                  'first_name',
                   'last_name',
                   'email',
                   'password1',
                   'password2'
                  ]

       def save(self,commit):
            user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)

       if commit:
           user.save()

       return user


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user']

    def save(self,commit):
         user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
         USN =self.cleaned_data['USN']
         year = self.cleaned_data['year'] 
         sem = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)

         if commit:
            user.save()

         return user
```

Have created UserProfile model in  models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9A-Z]*$', 'Only alphanumeric 
                                  characters are allowed.')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name = 
                                'profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    USN = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, validators= 
                          [alphanumeric])
    year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sem = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username

 def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
   if kwargs['created']:
       objects=models.Manager()
       user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
 post_save.connect(create_profile, sender = User)
```

I have used both the forms in Views.py -

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form_1 = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    form_2 = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form_1.is_valid() and form_2.is_valid():
        save_1 = form_1.save(commit = False)
        save_2 = form_1.save(commit = False)
        save_1.save()
        save_2.save()
        return render(request,'main/home.html')
else:
    form_1 = RegistrationForm()
    form_2 = UserProfileForm()
args = {'form_1':form_1,'form_2':form_2}
return render(request, 'account/register.html',args)
```

The username in the profile model object shows correctly, but other fields are not getting updated. I want other fields also getting updated in the profile object.

Comment: why do you call `user = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)` and `sem = super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)` inside your `UserProfileForm`? That obviously returns the wrong object (you're calling the super().save method of the `User` form, not the `UserProfile` form.) Also `sem = ...` is probably a mistake since it's the same as `user = ...`

Comment: In general, if you're on python 3, just call `super()` without specifying the class, will just do the right thing.

Comment: Have u tried `prefix` argument while instantiating your forms in view?

Comment: There's no point saving the forms with `commit=False` if you're then immediately going to call `save` without changing anything.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten for pointing out the mistake . Setting 'sem=...' was my bad. I am not sure how to set the `user = ...` . I am new to django . Can someone please guide me to make the right call.

Comment: This is just python. Just call `user_profile = super().save(commit=False)` and then save and return `user_profile` (I call it like that because it’s not a User). Your code is calling `super(RegistrationForm, self)` instead of `super(UserProfileForm, self)`. As mentioned if on python 3 you’re better off just using `super()` without arguments.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.